# Point symbol rotation in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, point, rotate

In QGis 2.x, I could rotate a point symbol towards the nearest geometry of a certain kind by using:

```
geomnearest('featuretype', 'BEARING')
```

This however does not work in QGIS 3.x, and I cannot find out what rotation command to use.

Answer (score 3):

`geomnearest` is a function of the **refFunctions** plugin, search it in the QGIS extension menu and install it, it's available in QGIS 3.*x*.

*see* [Plugin page](https://geogear.wordpress.com/2014/11/13/reffunctions-v1-0/) :

> `geomnearest(targetLayer,targetField)`
>
> Retrieve target field value from the nearest target feature in target layer

Comment: I have the QGIS 3.x compatible version of refFunctions installed, but that does not help.

Comment: You have already reported the issue, seems the developper works on the migration to the core ([link](https://github.com/enricofer/refFunctions/issues/13)]

Comment: My question is how to get to the result needed as geomnearest does not work, at least not in the way it did before. I would be very thankful for any help in how to achieve this.

Comment: It was not clear for me in your question, hence my answer thinking you hadn't installed the plugin.

Comment: Does anyone have experiences regarding if geomnearest should work now in Qgis 3.x as it did through the refFunctions plugin in Qgis 2.x . I have not found out how to achieve the above geomnearest(targetLayer,targetField) kind of result thorugh Qgis 3.x and the new refFunctions plugin.

Comment: Look at the description of the function in QGIS 3 : `overlay_nearest(layer:='airports', expression:="name", filter:= "Use"='Civilian', limit:=3) → an array of names, for up to the three closest civilian airports ordered by distance`